# Excel filter by value in one column and use output rows as parameter for another function

Tags: excel

When using regression in Excel I encounter a problem with passing in the parameters. Y is a dependent variable and X1,X2,X3,X4 are independent variables:

=LINEST(Data[Y];Data[X1]:Data[X4];;TRUE)

The requirement that I'm missing, is that it should take only rows with specific values in Data[status] column, for example {"married", "divorced"}. How to insert that condition into the function I have?

Answer (score 0):

**Array formula****:

`=LINEST(INDEX(Data[Y],N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Data[status],{"married","divorced"},0)),{1,1}*ROW(Data[Y])-MIN(ROW(Data[Y]))+1))))),INDEX(Data[[X1]:[X4]],N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Data[status],{"married","divorced"},0)),{1,1}*ROW(Data[Y])-MIN(ROW(Data[Y]))+1)))),),,TRUE)`

Regards

Comment: I don't know if you clearly see this is an array. The function in my last post only selects the second row and ignores rows 3 and 4. This is also why I still can't run the whole function from your post. Y,X1,X2,X3,X4,status;0,1,0,0,0,single;0,0,1,1,0,married;1,0,0,0,1,divorced;2,0,0,0,5,divorced

Comment: But whose is the function from your last post? It does not seem to bear any resemblance to the solution I posted. Why don't you add some data to your actual post, not these comment boxes, and explain precisely what it is you are trying to achieve. All these discussions on arrays are a little unhelpful, ultimately.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85326/discussion-on-answer-by-xor-lx-excel-filter-by-value-in-one-column-and-use-outpu).